# Набрать в рот воды

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Каково происхождение выражения "Набрать в рот воды"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение самодостаточное, говорить с водой во рту невозможно.
В подобных случаях указать на точный источник обычно невозможно, вернее всего какого-то одного и не существует.